# Apachectl "service already loaded" when it's not

Tags: apache, unix, terminal, localhost, httpd.conf

I am trying to learn a bit about the terminal and servers. I am following a course and in this course it states that you can start and stop the server apache (on mac) by using the command:

```
sudo apachectl start
```

But, when I do this, it comes back with a message saying that apache is already functioning. The full message:

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: service already loaded
```

Apache is clearly not running though:

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```

doesn't return any activity.

I expect this is something to do with the fact that the course I am following is for Yosemite and I am running El Capitan. I don't know much about the issue and I am trying to learn, but I can't even follow the course if I can't even start the server.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

P

edit ---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>org.apache.httpd</string>
        <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
        <dict>
                <key>XPC_SERVICES_UNAVAILABLE</key>
                <string>1</string>
        </dict>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/usr/sbin/httpd-wrapper</string>
                <string>-D</string>
                <string>FOREGROUND</string>
        </array>
        <key>OnDemand</key>
        <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: apache process is httpd not https

Comment: hi, sorry this is a typo here, i did write httpd in the terminal

Comment: Then the next step is to look at apache error log to see why it is not starting. Note the only issues where there are no logs when it tries to start can be related to a SSL config with a private key + cert mismatch or similar.

Comment: Can you run `apachectl configtest` and see if your config is OK? I believe your apache config has an error and then it fails. Also can you add the contents of `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist` to the question?

Comment: so, the command 'apachectl configtest' returns the following error: AH00526: Syntax error on line 20 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf:
Invalid command 'LockFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration.

Comment: also have edited the question with the org.apache.httpd.plist contents

Comment: the just remove that directive or make sure it points to a correct path. IIRC the default is good enough so you can safely comment/remove it.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely to be a config error. Run the following and fix any errors

```
sudo apachectl configtest
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
sudo apachectl stop
sudo apachectl start
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
apachectl status
```

This is probably the best way to check the status of Apache.

Comment: That just tell you to go to http://localhost:80/server-status in your browser, which is not much use if the problem is that apache isn't running correctly and not serving files which should be accessible in the browser