# No Apache process after restart in MoJave

Tags: macos, apache

I installed MoJave from Sierra and can't get apache to work,

I expect it to serve /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html

```
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    114 Jan  1 21:32 index.html
```

When I try to restart the server with,

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

and just in case with,

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart
```

I get,

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: service already loaded
```

But does 'loaded' mean 'running'?

Also there is no httpd process running,

```
$ ps aux | grep httpd
```

returns nothing.

And naturally when I navigate to localhost in the browser I get 'site can't be reached'.

I am running the default /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

I used the -k to like this,

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl -k restart
```

and this gave,

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 546 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 8 of /private/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/php5/libphp7.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/php5/libphp7.so, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:\n\t/usr/local/php5/libphp7.so: code signature in (/usr/local/php5/libphp7.so) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.\n\t/usr/local/php5/libphp7.so: stat() failed with errno=22
```

## Update

Then I went to,

```
/private/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf
```

and commented out,

```
#LoadModule php7_module        /usr/local/php5/libphp7.so

Now at least localhost/index.html works but I presume this disables index.php which is in the same place as index.html. The php code in index.php shows, it does not execute php.
```

I think this tutoral might help,

https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-apache-mysql-php-on-macos-mojave-10-14/

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Also, looks like duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48320702/apachectl-service-already-loaded-when-its-not

Comment: Thanks but there is no solution there other than a suggestion.

Comment: I tried the solution also and it is not working, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check your Apache config, you can also run:

```
apachectl configtest
```

You already commented the line causing Apache not to start. From here, you can add PHP to your Apache config this way:

First, locate your `httpd.conf` file path:

```
httpd -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE
```

You may also check with:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES
```

Then, open your `httpd.conf` file and try to look for a line starting with `LoadModule php`

If there's one comment it with `#`, If there's no such line, that's fine.

Just add the following line (for php7):

```
LoadModule php7_module path
```

or, for php5:

```
LoadModule php5_module path
```

and replace `path` with the result of the `find` command below (if you have several results, choose the path you want to be used with Apache, that is, the version you want):

```
find /usr/libexec /usr/local/ -type f -name "libphp*"
```

Finally, restart Apache: `sudo apachectl restart`